# Extract ticketcorner event seat prices from a venue map

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to use `beautifulsoup` to extract data from a `tooltipster` that is hovering over a map. Once it finds a point with information, it has to extract three different pieces of information. If it doesn't find anything it should start from the beginning again (tried using try and except for this). If it finds something, it should append it to a list and after print it. At the moment it does not extract anything and I have tried a couple of things.

In the screenshot, you see the information I'm looking to extract:[image: screenshot]

The page is this: [Page](https://www.ticketcorner.ch/event/art-on-ice-2023-hallenstadion-12731448/)

and my code is:

```
details = []
# Mouse Hover over the concert map and find the empty seats to extract the data.
for x in range(-250, 250, 10):
    for y in range(-250, 250, 10):
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                                                value='//*[@id="seatmap-tab"]/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]'),0, 0)
        actions.move_by_offset(x, y).perform()
        time.sleep(.4)
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        try:
            for div in soup.find_all(class_='sm-tooltip-title theme-headline-color'):
                for span in soup.find_all(class_='sm-tooltip-name theme-headline-color'):
                    for div in soup.find_all(class_='sm-tooltip-name theme-headline-color'):
                        details.append(tr.text.strip().replace('\n', ' '))
        except:

            break

print(details)
```

Comment: have you tried to save the page content `html = driver.page_source` and open it with your browser? if you are detected as scraper you  will redirected to another page that's (I guess) why your code doesn't work

Comment: if conversely you copy-paste the source page from your browser to a file and then scrape the file and you the desired results... then it is not the _soup_ but how make the request which fail. Did you add a user-agent?

Answer (score 0):

When I approach a task like this I usually go straight for the API (here: [`https://api.eventim.com/seatmap/api/SeatMapHandler`](https://api.eventim.com/seatmap/api/SeatMapHandler)), instead of trying to parse the output.

In your case that would require to obtain the necessary request parameters, first. Something like this works for me:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import urlencode

url = "https://www.ticketcorner.ch/event/art-on-ice-2023-hallenstadion-12731448/"

headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Not gonna tell',
  'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
  'Accept-Language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

# use BeautifulSoup to extract the <script> with the necessary request parameters
soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers,).text)
signature_json: dict = json.loads(soup.find('script', text=re.compile('seatmapOptions')).text)

# extract the parameters as dict to easily query them
parameters_list: list[list] = signature_json.get('seatmapOptions').get('additionalRequestParams').split('&')
parameters = dict()
for parameter in parameters_list:
    if len((item := parameter.split('='))) > 1:
        parameters[item[0]] = item[1]

# build the request URL
stub = f'https://api.eventim.com/seatmap/api/SeatMapHandler?smcVersion=v6.1&version=v6.2.11&cType=web&cId=8&'

event_parameters = {
    'evId': '12731448',
    'a_holds': '1',
    'a_rowRules': '1',
    'a_systemId': '1',
    'a_promotionId': parameters.get('a_promotionId'),
    'a_sessionId': parameters.get('a_sessionId'),
    'timestamp': parameters.get('timestamp'),
    'expiryTime': parameters.get('expiryTime'),
    'chash': parameters.get('chash'),
    'signature': parameters.get('signature'),
    'fun': 'json',
    'areaId': '0',
}

data: dict = requests.get(stub + urlencode(event_parameters)).json()
```

This is just a very basic example and you will probably have to add other query parameters to get seat information, eg `blockId`. The idea stays the same, though: get the necessary requerst parameter to authenticate against the API and then query the endpoint directly.

You might also get blocked at some point if your activity seems malicious...